# Recreating wrongfully collapsed content IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, tabs

A customer informed me that the content on one of my pages is wrongfully collapsed.

This is the page: http://www.polarpumpen.se/fortum

**This is what it looks like to the customer: ****
[image]

Unfortunatly, I can't recreate the problem and I don't have any info on what IE version she's using.

I've tried IE7, IE8, IE8, IE9, IE10 and compability mode of IE10. I still can't recreate it, hence not solve it...

Does anyone recognize this problem and can **point me in the right direction to recreate** it?

Thank you!

Comment: You can find the info of what browser she is using by inspecting the user agent as it is requested.

Comment: She is using IE11, even am getting the same in IE 11.

Comment: @AbstractChaos , it's just that I'm not in contact with her, and she is a customer that i'd rather not bother with this...

Comment: @VenomVendor , thank you i'm gonna try that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your customer is using IE11 as I tested, I too get the same.

After debugging, your seem to miss `float:left` in `#tabby-content`. Here is the SS after adding `float:left`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've downloaded IE11, but i still can't see the same problem. The customer saw the problem further down on the page, than your screen shot. Still, i followed your instructions. Can you see if anything has changed?

Comment: yes I see the updated version, seems good as in above SS, am afraid that you have huge white space. please remove `#inform-content {min:height:1800px;}` your site is good now (I too did the same mistake in the past). You should also learn about `clear:both`

Comment: Thank you, that `min-height` is set for mobile devices, for the text not to go outside the tab. I usually use `clear: both`. But i would be happy if you could help me by telling me where it's missing :)

Comment: adding min-height is of no use in your case, since you were missing float:left you were in need to min-height, you can give a try now in mobile device and check, about `clear:both` just saying :)